# CUDA Toolkit 4.1/4.2: nvcc Crashes with an Access Violation

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

I am developing a CUDA application for GTX 580 with Visual Studio 2010 Professional on Windows 7 64bit. My project builds fine with CUDA Toolkit 4.0, but nvcc crashes when I choose CUDA Toolkit 4.1 or 4.2 with the following error:

> 1>  Stack dump: 
>   1>  0.  Running pass 'Promote Constant Global' on module 'moduleOutput'. 
>   1>CUDACOMPILE : nvcc error : 'cicc' died with status 0xC0000005 (ACCESS_VIOLATION)

Strangely enough, the program compiles OK with "compute_10,sm_10" specified for "Code Generation", but "compute_20,sm_20" does not work. The code in question can be downloaded here:

http://www.meriken2ch.com/files/CUDA_SHA-1_Tripper_MERIKENs_Branch_0.04_Alpha_1.zip

(README.txt is in Japanese, but comments in source files are in English.)

I am suspecting a newly introduced bug in CUDA Toolkit 4.1/4.2. Has anybody encountered this issue? Is there any workaround for it? Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please try the publicly available CUDA 5.0 RC to see if this problem still exists and report back?

Comment: My project builds fine with CUDA 5.0 RC. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been a compiler bug in CUDA 4.x that is fixed in CUDA 5.0 (according to a comment from @meriken2ch, the project builds fine with CUDA 5.0 RC).